# Save, Save & Close and Close not working on Jumi module since Joomla 3.4.2

Tags: php, joomla, save, jumi

I recently updated a Joomla site to 3.4.2
and it ruined its Jumi module.
It was refusing to save.

I'm posting you the answer.

---

Answer (score 6):

On trying to save in Jumi module, your console [F12] probably throw this Error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'task' of null
```

What it is trying to do is send your "form" by ID
You'll see that your Form don't have a defined 'Id'

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm">
```

**All you need to do is:**

1) Go in this folder your_site\administrator\components\com_jumi\views\editapplication\tmpl\

2) Open default.php with a code/text editor.

3-a) At lines 44 and 144 , add the property id="adminForm"

Both lines should now look like

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
```

3-b) Save it.

Jumi should now be able save.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I was really frustrated with the three non working buttons on all components after a recent upgrade, but clearing browser cache and closing and reopening the browser seemed to solve it.

Comment: Good thing for you ! =), but clearing the browser's cache was'nt enough to solve my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324903/save-save-close-and-close-not-working-on-jumi-module-since-joomla-3-4-2?answertab=active#tab-top check this.